# extracting right hand side vector from JuMP model

Tags: julia, julia-jump

Is there a way to extract the right hand side vector from a JuMP model similar to the one used to extract the coefficients matrix (getconstrmatrix())? if there is no way to do so, how could i extract said information?

Comment: `getconstrLB()` and `getconstrUB()` might be what you are looking for (they take the same argument as `getconstmatrix()`)

Comment: Thank you @DanGetz! that's exactly what i was trying to find

Comment: Wrote the comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getconstrLB()` and `getconstrUB()` return the upper and lower bounds on the constraints, with equal values when the constraints are equalities. They take the same argument as `getconstmatrix()`.

The documentation Google found is [here](http://mathprogbasejl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lpqcqp.html#getconstrLB)